# newbie IOS 5: How do I get Facebook to return "About Me" data on the currently logged in user?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have Facebook authentication running fine for IOS 5, but need to pull down data on the logged-in user. I have gone over facebook's tutorial but lack the knowledge on implementing an FBRequestDelegate to handle my request.

Can you demonstrate how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

You should take the `user_about_me` user data permission before you access it.
FYI: [User Object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Then you can call graph API using below code.

> [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=bio" andDelegate:self];

FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#graph

> A successful request will callback request:didLoad: in your delegate.
>   The result passed to your delegate can be an NSArray, if there are
>   multiple results, or an NSDictionary if there is only a single result.

[FBRequestDelegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/FBRequestDelegate/)

Use the FBRequestDelegate protocol to handle the delegates. Refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#appnotifications)